# C++ code after a for loop doesn't execute

Tags: c++

It's a bit weird to me that the code after a `for` loop doesn't execute but the compiler doesn't raise any warning:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator> 

bool isVowel(char ch)
{
    char vowels[]{"aeiouAEIOU"};
    
    char *p = std::find(std::begin(vowels), std::end(vowels), ch);
    if (p != std::end(vowels))
    {
        std::cout << ch << " is a vowel" << '\n';
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << ch << " is not a vowel" << '\n';
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char name[]{"MollieU"};
    int numVowels{0};
    std::cout << name << '\n';
    int length{std::size(name)};
    for (char* ptr{name}; ptr < (name + length); ++ptr)
    {
        if (isVowel(*ptr))
            ++numVowels;
    }
    
    std::cout << name << " has " << numVowels << " vowels." << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

It has outputs like:

```
MollieU
M is not a vowel
o is a vowel
l is not a vowel
l is not a vowel
i is a vowel
e is a vowel
U is a vowel
```

But `std::cout << name << " has " << numVowels << " vowels." << '\n';` is never run. Whatever code I put after the loop is never run. I am not sure if `return 0` is run or not, but the file is compiled successfully. I am using `g++ -std=c++2a` on `osx`.

Comment: As soon as I put the missing `#include <algorithm>`: [I cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fdAZWkqYlbkgUwze).

Comment: Successful compilation does not mean squat. I don't know where people get the idea that if a program compiles, it should work as intended. A program compiles when it doesn't contain any _syntax_ errors. You can make all the logic errors you want, it'll still compile. You need to learn how to debug you programs. If code after your `for` loop isn't getting executed, then in all likelihood your loop never ends.

Comment: Can't repro this.  Code compiles and works as expected. This includes the final `cout` statement

Comment: What makes you say the output line is "never run"? What happens, _exactly_? Where do you run this? In a console? IDE? Something else? How do you start the program?

Comment: How do you execute this? It is not a case of "Program finished but I missed the last output becaue the output window closed too quickly.", is it?

Comment: I've tried it on the Repl.it online compiler. It runs as expected: `MollieU has 5 vowels.`. Only difference is that I added `#include<algorithm>`. Try to flush with `std::endl` instead of `'\n'` for a new line. Probably Repl.it automatically flushed the output

Comment: Is it really expected that MollieU has 5 vowels? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following:

```
int length { std::size(name) - 1 };
```

Comment: Yes, I just found the `std::size()` or `sizeof()` returns 1 more length than `std::strlen()` as they include the trailing `\0` at the end of the array. Using a fixed length or `std::strlen()` in `<cstring>` makes the code works.

Comment: However, this doesn't seem to be an explanation for the actual problem that you had. It only explains the wrong result of 5 vowels vs. 4 vowels.

Comment: @Pedro, the loop won't stop with a length greater than 7 and never execute code after that on my machine I am using `g++ -std=c++2a`. But the same code (length=8) produce different results on `repl.it` with `clang c++17`. On my machine, it stays inside the loop without the ouput of the last line but on `repl.it` it compares trailing `\0` with another `\0` in `vowels[]` and output the last line as `MollieU has 5 vowels.`

Comment: Your loop condition doesn't have anything to do with what is happening inside `isVowel`. Have you ever tried adding a `cout` or two to the for loop body to see what is actually happening? You could output the addresses `ptr` and `name + length` at the beginning of each iteration and add some other `cout` at the end of each iteration, then you'll know what's really going on. The only explanation I can see is that it gets stuck in the `find`.